# executing sql server query from a file

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am going to use the FTP task tool to pull a file into the SQL server from a remote host. Is stored procedure the best way to execute a query contained within the file without doing it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell  'sqlcmd -S ' + @DBServerName + ' -d  ' + @DBName + ' -i ' + @FilePathName
```